# Chaining Commands in herbstluftwm depending on the number of windows in the frame

Tags: linux, shell-script, window-manager, twm

I am wanting to configure window close behaviour so that, when I press the <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>. If the frame has one or no windows, close the window and remove the frame. If it has more than 1 window, only close the focused window. This makes it easier to close the frame/window dynamically depending on the windows in the frame.

I was able to solve the first part of the requirement by editing the config file as below. ie. if the frame has one or no windows close the window and removes the frame.

`hc keybind $Mod-n and . compare tags.focus.curframe_wcount lt 2 . chain , close , remove`

However, I am unable to chain the second part, where if the frame has more than 1 window, just close the focussed window. I tried below two options.

1. Tried chaining with an **or**

`hc keybind $Mod-n or | and . compare tags.focus.curframe_wcount lt 2 . chain , close , remove | close`

2. Tried writing a separate function

```
hc keybind $Mod-Shift-q close_frames

close_frames(){
    WinCurFrame=$(hc attr tags.focus.curframe_wcount)
    [[ WinInCurFrame < 2 ]] && hc close;remove || hc close
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Identified the way of achieving it. There is a configuration option in Herbstluftwm which enables this behaviour.
https://herbstluftwm.org/herbstluftwm.html

> **close_or_remove**
> Closes the focused window or removes the current frame if no window is focused. In floating mode, this acts as the close command.

> **close_and_remove**
> Closes the focused window and removes the current frame if no other window is present in that frame. In floating mode, this acts as the close command.